# Symfony formtype query builder associations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, symfony-forms

I'm with Symfony 3.2, and I would like to have a form type for an entity that is associated to another one:

```
class Aliment
    // ...
    private enseigneId;
    // ...
```

and

```
class Enseigne
    // ...
    private nomEnseigne
    // ...
```

and Aliment.enseigneId refers to Enseigne.id, but what I want to make in my form (CRUD, for the creation one) is to let the user choising an ID but I want to display the value of that ID instead, so it's easier for the user.

This is what I have in my form type (Ticket) :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('date', DateTimeType::class, array(
            'data' => new \DateTime()
        ))
        ->add('aliments')
        ->add('prixTotal')
        ->add('recapitulatif')
        ->add('modePaiement')
        ->add('enseigneId', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Enseigne',
            'choice_label' => function ($enseigne) {
                /** @var $enseigne Enseigne */
                return $enseigne->getNomEnseigne();
            }

        ));
}
```

But it keeps displaying the integer 0 instead (while getNomEnseigne() return a string and the database is well filled with correct dataset), I don't know how to do..
I want it to be stored as an integer, but I want to display (in the choice field) as the value of the Id it's referring to.

```
Id | nomEnseigne | ...
-----------------------
0  | LECLERC     | ...
1  | LIDL        | ...
```

With the above example, the user would see the string "LECLERC" but the integer 0 would be stored instead.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try other ways like

```
'choice_label' => 'nomEnseigne',
```

or realizing __toString() method of Enseigne entity

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    if (empty($this->nomEnseigne) {
        return 'enseigne ' . $this->id;
    }

    return (string) $this->nomEnseigne;
}
```

Comment: I cannot fill choice_label with 'nomEnseigne' as I only have the ID (enseigneId refering to an Enseigne entity), at the beginning I thought it was possible with a query builder, but I don't know how to do either.

Comment: Ok so now it's displaying the name correctly, but when I want to save my changes, I got and exception telling me that an object of 'Enseigne' could not be converted to 'int'. Is it because 'enseigneId' is an integer but I'm returning a string with the call to 'getNomEnseigne' in my form.

Comment: wich way did you use? for me both works fine.

the problem with saving should be elsewhere, because choice label doesn't affect on choice value. could you show the code of controller, that handles the form?